# jQuery Mobile click event works only once, after DOM is changed due to the click event

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to bind a click event like the following using jQuery Mobile multi-page setting (this page is not the main page):

**HMTL**

```
<div data-role="page" id="thirdPage">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="segment"></div>
      <div class="segment"></div>
      <div class="segment prev"></div>
      <div class="segment now"></div>
      <div class="segment next"></div>
      <div class="segment"></div>
      <div class="segment"></div>
      <div class="segment"></div>
      <div class="segment"></div>
      <div class="segment"></div>
      <div class="segment"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.segment.next').on('click', function(){
var seg = $(this);
var width = seg.width();
var currentLeft = parseInt($('.wrapper').css('left'));
var left = currentLeft - width;
    //using transit.js for css animation
$('.wrapper').transition({left : left}, 300, 'linear', function(){
                    $('.segment').filter('.prev').removeClass('prev');
                    $('.segment').filter('.now').removeClass('now');
                    seg.removeClass('next').addClass('now');
                    seg.prev().addClass('prev');
                    seg.next().addClass('next');
                });
});
```

The most of the things seems to be working: it removes/adds classes as it should and animate wrapper to the left with the right amount of pixel. However, the $('.segment.next') part isn't working correctly - even though the right $('.segment') has the class "next" after the first animation, the click event is not bound to this "new" $('.segment.next') from the second time on. Instead, the click event is still bound to the original $('.segment.next'). Is there any way to fix this issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#thirdPage').on('click', '.segment.next', function(){
    ...
});
```

Delegation works by referencing descendents of an element that's always present. You don't have to use document, but you need to use some ancestor that isn't dynamic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, isherwood! It worked perfectly. I honestly did not know that the jQuery .on() only works for the element that isn't dynamic.